# Laravel Category + Slug of Article

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes, slug

I'm attempting to build a blog like application with the latest version of laravel. I'm trying to figure out how to add the category slug from the categories table and then add the article slug. Examples and pictures below.

localhost/test-category/howtomake

app/http/controllers/ArticlesController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Article;

class ArticlesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $articles =  Article::all();
        return view('articles.index')->with('articles', $articles);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($slug)
    {
        $articles = Article::where('slug', $slug)->first();
        return view('articles.show')->with('articles', $articles);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }


}
```

app/Article.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'articles';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = true;
}
```

routes/web.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('articles', 'ArticlesController');
```

database table (articles)
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxMjN.png]

database table (catorgeries)
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJkpa.png]

Any help and suggestions will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SO to distribute that content. By SO policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please read more at [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default key for a route in the model

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```